# Automatically scroll to a specific part of the home (root) page from a separate url back link

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, js-scrollintoview

I have this base  code on my website's home page (myexample.com):

```
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById("pizza3").scrollIntoView( {behavior: 'smooth'} );
}, 2000);
```

Now as it stands, the scrolling effect will fire on every call to the home page (myexample.com). I actually want this script snippet to fire, AND ONLY FIRE, when the home page's url string explicitly reads: **myexample.com#pizza3**

How might the base code be modified to achieve?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should catch the last 7 digits of your URL and check them for the pizza tag:

```
let url = window.location.href;
let tagStr = url.substr(url.length - 7);
if (tagStr == '#pizza3') {

setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("pizza3").scrollIntoView( {behavior: 'smooth'} );
}, 2000);
      }
```

Comment: I appreciate your willingness to answer, James (^5). But unfortunately, your modified code version did not produce the desired effect. Upon accessing myexample.com#pizza3, the page remained static, and did not automatically scroll to the page element with id="pizza3".

Google Chrome's console revealed the following:
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier:
if (tagStr == ''#pizza3') {**

Comment: Bummer! Still does not scroll to the tag element. The page remains at the top -- when the url string is defined with **myexample.com#pizza3**

Thank you for trying, though.. :)

Comment: It works in my test example... What exactly are you typing into the URL bar? Obviously not myexample.com, can you copy paste what you are doing.

Comment: You totally rock!!  Thank you! It works like a champ..  *I performed a typo myself, lol...  when entering the url string.